# On a generator of a continuous-time Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $S$ be a countable set with discrete topology and let $X=(\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0},\{P_x\}_{x \in S})$ be a continuous-time Markov chain on $S$. We assume that each $x \in S$ is a exponential holding state and  let $\tau_x$ denote the waiting time of $X$ at $x.$ Let $\lambda_x$ denotes the parameter of $\tau_x$ and assume that $\sup_{x \in S}\lambda_x<\infty.$

Let $\mathcal{B}_b(S)$ denote the set of all bounded functions on $S$. Define $L\colon \mathcal{B}_b(S) \to \mathcal{B}_b(S)$ by
\begin{align*}
Lf(x)=\lambda(x)\sum_{y \in S}P_{x}(X_{\tau_x}=y)(f(y)-f(x)).
\end{align*}

Writing $\{p_t\}_{t>0}$ for the semigroup of $X$, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{p_{t}f(x)-f(x)}{t}=Lf(x).
\end{align*}
for any $x \in X$ and any $f \in \mathcal{B}_b(S)$. This convergence is also bounded. However, rhe proof I know is lengthy and uses a discrete-time Markov chain. Can we directly compute the limit $
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{p_{t}f(x)-f(x)}{t}$ ?

For $t>0$, $x \in S$, and $f \in \mathcal{B}_b(S)$,  we have
\begin{align*}
p_tf(x)&=f(x)P_{x}(t<\tau_x)+E_{x}[f(X_t)\colon t\ge \tau_x] \\
&=f(x)e^{-t\lambda_x}+E_{x}[f(X_t)\colon t\ge \tau_x].
\end{align*}
How should I calculate the second term in the above equation?

Comment: the second term you mention is a joint law issue, which is usually tricky even in the case of random walk. Do you have some original problem that you are trying to answer using the $p_{t}f$? Maybe we can get bounds if you need.